# Postgresql Query with joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have 6 tables that I'm trying to connect together in 1 query; however, I can't quite figure out how to write the query.

Here are my tables in bold and the columns that they contain.

**pg**
pgid

**ipg**
ipgid
roid
pgid

**ug**
ugid

**iug**
iuid
roid
ugid

**ro**
roid
inid

**in**
inid

My goal is to output the `inid` field given certain criteria from the **pg** and **ug** tables. I want to find all the `inid` entries where `pg.pgid=1` and `ug.ugid=2`. This involves a a lot of joins and I think some select in statments but I'm not familiar enough with how to piece that all together.

Here is what I have so far...

```
SELECT inid
FROM in
INNER JOIN ro  ON in.inid  = ro.inid
INNER JOIN iug ON ro.roid  = iug.roid
INNER JOIN ug  ON iug.ugid = ug.ugid
INNER JOIN ipg ON ro.roid  = ipg.roid
INNER JOIN pg  ON ipg.pgid = pg.pgid
WHERE pg.pgid = 1
  AND ug.ugid = 2
```

Comment: Aren't you getting the result you're looking for? Btw, I think the join on `pg` might unnecesary; it will only filter results if there is no `pgid=1`.

Comment: What is the error that you have?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot name your table `in`, that is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in every SQL standard and in PostgreSQL. You will get a syntax error if you try. You can still force the system to accept it if you [double quote the name](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) `CREATE TABLE "in" ...` but then you have to remember to double-quote it every time you use it and you will get confusing error messages. In short: don't do that.
I renamed the table `tbl_in` and gave it an alias in the query.

Also, `inid` is ambiguous as SELECT item. Either use `USING` as join condition (then only *one* column `inid` is in the result set) or table-qualify the column name.

Otherwise the query looks fine:

```
SELECT i.inid    -- ambiguous without table-qualification
FROM   tbl_in i  -- renamed table
JOIN   ro  ON i.inid   = ro.inid
JOIN   iug ON ro.roid  = iug.roid
JOIN   ug  ON iug.ugid = ug.ugid
JOIN   ipg ON ro.roid  = ipg.roid
JOIN   pg  ON ipg.pgid = pg.pgid
WHERE  pg.pgid = 1
AND    ug.ugid = 2;
```

---

If you have **foreign key constraints** between `pg` and `ipg` and between `ug` and `iug`, then you can simplify:

```
SELECT i.inid    -- ambiguous without table-qualification
FROM   tbl_in i  -- renamed table
JOIN   ro  ON i.inid   = ro.inid
JOIN   iug ON ro.roid  = iug.roid
JOIN   ipg ON ro.roid  = ipg.roid
WHERE  ipg.pgid = 1
AND    iug.ugid = 2;
```

... because once found in `iug` / `ipg` the values are guaranteed to be present in `up` / `pg`.

Comment: That worked just like  you said Erwin. I had to change some of the table names because they were too long and I wanted to keep it simple. I didn't realize that I created an IN table name. The query works perfect now thanks.